# Permanent Loading... in Smartedit preview

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I am having some issues with previewing pages in SmartEdit. Sometimes the Loading... is stuck there forever, and this issue appears to be related to the DOM loading time.

If I have the devtools console up, chances are the page will load 1/10 times, on Mozilla it works 10/10 with no browser console up. So basically, the setup seems to be fine, everything works as intended except for this annoying permanent loading issue.

In the network tab the cx-preview crashes, gets a 200 error, and the Loading remains, although the components in the page are visible behind the Loading overlay

Also before the 200 error from the cx-preview call, there is another red one with the text (cancelled) at the end.

[image]

[image]

Update:
There seems to be an issue here where the cx-preview is set in the serializer.
If I remove the state.url.length condition, the loading will be permanent.

```
import { RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import {
  ActivatedRouterStateSnapshot,
  CmsActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  PageContext,
  PageType
} from '@spartacus/core';

export class AokCuRouterStateSerializer {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): ActivatedRouterStateSnapshot {
    const { url } = routerState;
    const { queryParams } = routerState.root;

    let state: CmsActivatedRouteSnapshot = routerState.root as CmsActivatedRouteSnapshot;
    let cmsRequired = false;
    let context: PageContext;

    while (state.firstChild) {
      state = state.firstChild as CmsActivatedRouteSnapshot;

      if (state.data && state.data.cxCmsRouteContext) {
        context = state.data.cxCmsRouteContext;
      }

      if (
        !cmsRequired &&
        (context ||
          (state.routeConfig &&
            state.routeConfig.canActivate &&
            state.routeConfig.canActivate.find(
              x => x && x.guardName === 'CmsPageGuard'
            )))
      ) {
        cmsRequired = true;
      }
    }
    const { params } = state;

    if (state.url.length > 0 && state.url[0].path === 'cx-preview') {
      context = {
        id: 'smartedit-preview',
        type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE
      };
    } else {
      if (params['productCode']) {
        context = { id: params['productCode'], type: PageType.PRODUCT_PAGE };
      } else if (params['orderCode']) {
        context = {
          id: 'order-' + params['orderCode'],
          type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE
        };
      } else if (params['categoryCode']) {
        context = { id: params['categoryCode'], type: PageType.CATEGORY_PAGE };
      } else if (params['brandCode']) {
        context = { id: params['brandCode'], type: PageType.CATEGORY_PAGE };
      } else if (state.data.pageLabel !== undefined) {
        context = { id: state.data.pageLabel, type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE };
      } else if (!context) {
        if (state.url.length > 0) {
          const pageLabel =
            '/' + state.url.map(urlSegment => urlSegment.path).join('/');
          context = {
            id: pageLabel,
            type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE
          };
        } else {
          context = {
            id: 'homepage',
            type: PageType.CONTENT_PAGE
          };
        }
      }
    }

    return { url, queryParams, params, context, cmsRequired };
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some code to the question. Where is this loading? How is it started? What is the logic to hide it? We have to understand which of these logics is failing.

Comment: if you are not familiar with smartedit you cannot answer this question, unfortunatelly there is not smartedit tag here. the whiteliststorefront is set to https://localhost:4200, allowedOrigins and Headers as in SAP documentation and storefrontPreviewRoute set to cx-preview. The issue is weird as some async data must be failing somehow in the editor preview because it only works sometimes.

Comment: I see that if the DOM loading time is short, it always works, so it could be related to the fact that the smartedit editor pop-ups faster than the actual component rendering or something like that.

Comment: @aepifano I have update with some maybe relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an issue related to both SmartEdit and Spartacus and will be fixed somwhere in the future: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/2358 - check last updates